# How to improve WPF path Geometry rendering in combination with Windows desktop scaling?

Tags: wpf, path, geometry, scaling, blur

Here's an WPF issue I was never able to find a workaround for. I'm creating software with a Windows 10 look, which means it uses buttons with icons that contains elements of 1px wide. The icons are WPF geometries written in the WPF Geometry mini language, as described [here](https://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/).

These geometries don't scale well when Windows is configured with a desktop scaling of more than 100%. This image shows the issue (left = scaling 100%, right = scaling 125%).

[image]

The path geometry in the above image is:

```
<Geometry x:Key="Playlist">F1 M 0,0L 0,1 17,1 17,0 M 0,6 0,7 21,7 21,6 M 0,12 0,13 13,13 13,12 0,12 Z</Geometry>
```

This is then used in a button by setting the button's content to a path with the geometry as data:

```
<Button><Path Fill="White" Data="{StaticResource Playlist}"/></Button>
```

I tried all combinations of UseLayoutRounding and SnapsToDevicePixels true and false on the path. SnapsToDevicePixels gives the best result but it still doesn't look right. The image on the right is the best I can get.

So the question: is there a method to add graphics to a WPF application, in such way that they scale perfectly when using Windows desktop scaling?

Comment: Your `Path` shape should have `Fill` set instead of `Stroke`. That would look great and expected ***unless*** you want user to be able to see ***a hole*** (not even 1 pixel height) inside a rectangle having width of `1` pixel. It tries to just render the edges (the distance between top and bottom edges is just `1` while the edge itself has a thickness of `1`). That's impossible to be rendered correctly. As I said you need to set `Fill`, then the whole rectangle will be filled and render correctly (you have 3 rectangles, each one renders a horizontal line).

Comment: OK, it seems I wasn't clear and complete in my original post, so I edited after your comment. I indeed set the Fill Property to some color in my path. Geometries don't scale well when setting the Fill Property. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Haven't you think, that perhaps there is no way to clearly display 1 px scaled to 125%? It's gonna be either 2px wide line, where 1px line will be transparent in some degree, or 1px line.

Comment: Of course I thought of that. But I would then expect WPF to render it consistently: either always 1px, or 2px or with the same amount of blur for all lines. But if you look at the lines above, the sharpness differs per line.